# Multipart form data file upload using WSO2 API manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have rest service to upload files and it is working fine.Now I created API in API manager and also given the same file upload service as the production endpoint. But now I am getting an error in my backed server while uploading the file using API manager endpoint.

Comment: What is the error log you got?

Comment: my service is accepting one file with some body contents.while i am uploading through the API manger some how my body is missing.so the body reading function throwing null pointer exception

Comment: shall i change any configuration to support multipart in API manger or any <tag> to use in API

Comment: Do you get any error stack in APIManger server? check wso2carbon.log file for error logs

Comment: there is no error in carbon log,It seems some content type issue or file missing issue

Comment: got solution ,see my answer.Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution,Need to enable Binary Relay builders in axis2.xml file to use the multipart/form-data message formatting and also ensure that there  is no custom header with request  to handle multipart data.

```
 <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

  <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

Comment: Just to add - We have to enable all the <messageBuilder> & <messageFormatter> mappings containing contentType="multipart/form-data" in axis2.xml
There are total 4 mappings in axis2.xml.

Comment: try this: http://www.vitharana.org/2015/07/invoke-file-upload-spring-service-using.html