# Request parameters are not passed to the backend service

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I configured a REST webservice (a Spring Boot webapplication) on WSO2 AM and used the default /* mapping for resources. My webservice takes an assignee (text) and file parameters.

When I perform the calls, I've noticed that request parameters are not forwarded (HTTP Headers are) to the backed services. For example:

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-PD20-BillingSubscriptionId: e87d4400-b05f-4f40-9c39-06ae4d28cf4d" -H "Authorization: Bearer rrxRV5F6jdkSBcEPXv7I1yFl2x8a" -F "documentFile=@src/test/resources/sample-files/test-fea-1firma.pdf" -F "assignee=bla.bla@gmail.com" http://api.linksmt.it:8280/fea/1.0.0/signRequest

As you can see, It's a form that posts 2 fields, one of them being a file and another a simple text field.

The call is succesfully forwarded to the backed service but without the actual fields values (the headers instead are correctly passed, though their keys are lower-cased, that is "X-PD20-BillingSubscriptionId" is passed as "x-pd20-billingsubscriptionid").

Any hint on why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the same as described in [multipart form data file upload using WSO2 API manger ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025525/multipart-form-data-file-upload-using-wso2-api-manger) and I had to uncomment the declarations for

within the $WSO2_AM/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file (and restart the server).