# WSO2 api manager not sending uploaded multiple files to backend server

Tags: python, flask, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have built a python webservices application using flask.

After creation of swagger document, I published the api in WSO2 API manager.

The publish of API and subscription to the API are successful. 
I am able to get authentication token as well.

**What I am doing**

1. To consume the API, in Postman/Angular application I am uploading 2 excel file
2. Files are then sent to WSO2 server url which then sends it to python server
3. When python server receives the file, it parses it.
4. Does some calculations and returns the response data object.

Now the problem is at step 3. The files received at Python end are not in the excel format. The data of both the file are combined into one FileStorage object.

Please see the snapshot below

[Instead of two One FileStorage object received in request.files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ3Im.png)

I am trying this all in postman as well as with an angular application and both doesn't work. 
I even tried it via swagger at published app's page in WSO2 API manager but that also doesn't works.

[Sending Files Via WSO2 Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HNBa.png)

**What only works**

When I try the Swagger of published app, **Or** when I consume the services via postman making a request directly to python's server.

I am getting both the files in proper required format.

[File received properly when tried with python app's swagger page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMWYE.png)

Can you please help me to understand as to what I might be doing wrong.

I am using content type as below

```
'content-type: multipart/form-data;
```

Comment: You're sending 2 files at once?

Comment: Yeah @Bee , Two files against two separate parameters in form body, in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging up I found my resolution at [Multipart form data file upload using WSO2 API manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025525/multipart-form-data-file-upload-using-wso2-api-manager)

I added the

```
<messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
            class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
            class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```

inside the **JSON Message Builders** and **JSON Message Formatters** section in axis2.xml file at

```
<API-M_HOME>repository\conf\axis2\axis2.xml
```